# Clear joomla Session array values

Tags: php, session, joomla

I have a search form with 3 multi-selections. Everything works fine, but when I go back to the page the previous choice remains stored, even if nothing is selected in the field. I thought about cleaning the session:

in my search page:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->clear('com_jsjobsprovincia', null);
$session->clear('com_jsjobsjobcategory', null);
$session->clear('com_jsjobsjobsubcategory', null);
```

But don't work.

I tried to print the session:

```
[com_jsjobsjobcategory] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 2
                                )

                            [com_jsjobsjobsubcategory] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 111
                                )

                            [com_jsjobsprovincia] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 242
                                    [1] => 243
                                )
```

How should i do? thank you

pa

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather use `$session->setVar('com_jsjobsprovincia', null);`

Comment: it should, then something else must be playing with the session as well. did you try to display session constants before and after clearing ? and you might need in fact  to reset the data using `JFactory::getApplication()->setUserState()`

Comment: after searching and going back to the back page, even if the fields are not selected, it keeps the previous selection in memory..

Comment: i told you, maybe it's stored in user state. but i don't see your whole code, so hard to say.